# Web Scraping in C# just isn't working as expected

Tags: c#, web, screen-scraping

I have been trying to Scrape some data from a certain web site but it seems like my code is not behaving as expected. It is just not getting me the html page.

```
    public Scraper()
    {
        BGWorker.DoWork += GetHtml;
        BGWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    static void GetHtml(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading Data...");
        
        ScrapingBrowser _ScrapingBrowser = new ScrapingBrowser();

        WebPage webPage = _ScrapingBrowser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("https://www.goodwebsite.com"));

        Console.WriteLine(webPage.Html);
        Console.WriteLine("Got the Data");
    }
```

Comment: What *is* it getting you, then? I'm afraid there's nothing we can really say based on your question

Comment: Did you see any of the messages? Any errors?

Comment: Just a suggesstion; I would use another library (https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp) for web-scraping, or Selenium. It is easy, common, update-to-date and has extensive samples. Also there are tons of samples and articles for Selenium.

Comment: Are you using the `ScrapingBrowser` from [tag:scrapysharp]: https://github.com/rflechner/ScrapySharp?

Comment: `https://www.goodwebsite.com` seems to be dead, it redirects to `park.above.com` or `ww38.qfind.net`.  Are you trying to scrape these websites?  Or are you trying to scrape `https://www.goodwebsite.com`, which seems to be a stub?  Also, can you clarify exactly what nuget or other library you are using `ScrapingBrowser` from?

Comment: Assuming we know the library you are using, your code works for other web pages such as [https://stackoverflow.com/q/63325456/3744182](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dKnKYO), see https://dotnetfiddle.net/dKnKYO.  `https://www.goodwebsite.com` specifically throws a `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (302) Found.` exception, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/4ZRATt.  302 means that the URI of requested resource has been changed temporarily. What do you want to do in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use C# Selenium, just install it from the NuGet package manager.
It would look something like this:

```
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bikes.com/");
            var source = driver.PageSource;

            Console.WriteLine(source);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ScrapySharp make sure it is updated (newest) version.

To display HTML of **scraped** webpage you're missing `.InnerHtml` after `webPage.Html` :

```
static void GetHtml(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading Data...");
        
        ScrapingBrowser _ScrapingBrowser = new ScrapingBrowser();

        WebPage webPage = _ScrapingBrowser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("https://www.goodwebsite.com"));

        Console.WriteLine(webPage.Html.InnerHtml);
        Console.WriteLine("Got the Data");
    }
```

Basically you were just outputting object type instead of value.